# Templating with href in angular (4)

Tags: angular

So I know that in Angular 2 we can simply substitute ng-href for href in order to make templated urls work, but it doesn't work for me in Angular 4.  I can't find any documentation for it on angular.io either, so how does it work?

Edit: Maybe I have the version #s confused.  I'm concerned with the latest Angular (angular.io)

I want to link to external stylesheets, like 
`link rel="stylesheet" href="...">`

where ... is {{link}}, link = https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css

Comment: what does "it doesn't work for me" mean?  As far as I know, `ng-href` is AngularJs (1.x), not Angular (2.x+).  What is it you are actually trying to do?  "templated urls" doesn't explain enough.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

AngularJS required that you use `ng-href` because there were issues with binding expressions to some types of DOM elements and attributes.

This problem doesn't exist in Angular now.

The following will work as expected:

```
<a href="{{your expression here}}"></a>
```

You can also bind using the `attr` prefix like this:

```
<a [attr.href]="your expression here"></a>
```

As others have mentioned. If you are using routing and want to add a `href` attribute to a specific route. Use the `routerLink` directive as it will add the `href` attribute to `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 19):

The main difference between Angular 2 and 4 is `@angular/Router`

use this as route

```json
[{ path: 'xyz', component: XYZComponent}]
```

and redirect as

```html
<a routerLink='/xyz' >xyz</a>
```

Comment: this answer most useful for me by using routerLink, thanks

Answer (score 8):

Don't use `href="page"` and `ng-href="page"` however use `routerLink="/page"`

Comment: What about links to external website.

Answer (score 4):

Should be using routerLink for generating links

https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink